# Unable to Access File System in Azure

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-files

I have deployed my ASP.Net MVC website in Azure.
I have also created a FileShare in Azure. Both Website and FileShare belongs to same ResourceGroup.

The FileShare is something like `https://mysitedirectory.file.core.windows.net/myfiles/`
Now inside this FileShare I want to dynamically Create, Delete, Rename folders from my azure site. I also want to save, delete files from these folders.

In below example, I am trying to create **NewFolder**.
I tried:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("https://mysitedirectory.file.core.windows.net/myfiles/NewFolder")
```

From my azure site but it does not work.

I also tried:

```
Directory.CreateDirectory("\\mysitedirectory.file.core.windows.net\myfiles\NewFolder")
```

to create NewFolder but it's also not working.
Can you please suggest ?

Answer (score 0):

Depending on *where* you have deployed your ASP.NET MVC site you can either *mount* the share to be able to use the `Directory.CreateDirectory` method (only if you deployed it to a VM). Or, in case you deployed the site to an Azure WebSite (PaaS) you have to use the [Azure Storage Library for .NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt347887.aspx).

Also worth reading: [Get started with Azure File storage on Windows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-in/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files)

Answer (score 0):

According to docs, you need to [mount FileShare](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#mount-the-file-share) to machine you want access it from. Locating both (web site and file share) in one resource group is not the same.

As soon as it's not too easy (or even not possible?) to manage VM where your web app is running in - you can't use file share from your MVC app "directly" with `System.IO` classes - you should [use Azure Storage Client library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-dotnet-how-to-use-files#develop-with-file-storage)